# Looking for a GUI Subversion client for iOS

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, ui, subversion

I'm looking for an iOS app, preferably for iPhone, that can browse Subversion repositories.

I have found a few on the iTunes store—Code Viewer, iVersions, iRepoEditor—but reviews are either non-existent or swing wildly from one to five stars. All I'm looking for is a way to view secured repositories and copy content out of the files. I don't need to do editing or subsequent check-ins. Syntax coloring would be nice, but not necessary. I'm not looking for an ultimate-do-everything-under-the-sun here, just something that is reliable enough to use while on the road for a quick look at the latest project iteration here or there.

Does anyone have any experience with any of them, and what were your impressions?

**UPDATE:** Even though no one has answered the specific question, I've still gotten some great feedback that I think could be useful. Based on the responses, here are a couple things that I think will help guide edits...

- The repository is stored on a third-party SVN hosting site, [projectlocker.com](http://projectlocker.com/) I'm not sure there is a way for me to SSH in to their servers, but they do use Trac as part of their hosting package.
- The imputes for doing this comes from my using my svn repository to store and manage my homework and handouts for class, and also for answering questions about work projects in meetings. So, I'm looking for a relatively easy way to access these documents in a pinch if need be.
- I am open to options outside of simply getting an app that can read SVN repositories as long as the alternative is relatively easy. I use a GUI SVN client for a reason. ;-)

Comment: Good question. A vague alternative could be SSH into a box what has a subversion client :o with the new Panic SSH client for iOS or a VNC connection. But let us know if you eventually decide to try one.

Comment: Hmmm, first have to cancel my jetlag before flagging as duplicate... The one of yesterday was for MacOS, not iOS... Sorry :-/

Comment: In case you haven't thought of doing this, I'm guessing the best bet here would be replicating the SVN into a web repository of some sort. HTML5 baby! :P

Comment: @Martin, @Cawas, @mspasov: I have updated my question to better guide answers. These are all great suggestions.

Comment: Well, seems like you're going with **Trac** soon enough!

Comment: @PhilipRegan Have you tried iRepoEditor? How was it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excuse me for not answering your question, but IMHO it's better and more robust to follow the development via web, not via app.

You should be able to read the whole repository via http/https if your SVN is hosted via the [apache svn module](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.apache).

Another great way to monitor changes is to use some web-based frontend, which follows repository changes. A great tool (which I use and recommend) is [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw some alternatives to the list, [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) (they also have a similar "free" plan), seems to have a couple of apps that allow you to access the whole service and see your repos:

1. [MagicBean](http://www.magicbeanapp.com/)
2. [Habichuelas](http://www.microedition.biz/habichuelas/)

I am, however, not entirely sure if you can browse the SVN files… :(

Comment: +1 if only for the fact that it makes me reconsider Beanstalk for my hosting.

Comment: @Phillip I have a Bronze plan and it's very reliable, not much Xp with the "deployment" thing (which they happily use a "the" selling point).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [BugBranch](http://bugbranch.com), it lets you check out Subversion repositories to your iPhone or iPad.

Comment: While it wasn't one that the OP came across, unfortunately it falls into his negative criterion of having no reviews whatsoever. Have you personally used it? If so, then let the OP know which of his needs it addresses.

Answer (score 0):

SVN Repo Browser Pro https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/svn-repo-browser-pro/id603351327?mt=8 will let you browse repos from an iPhone or iPad and export files to other apps such as Microsoft Office, OneDrive or any app that can accept that file type.

Does a few other SVN things like file diffing and showing change logs. Its a pretty simple but fast app and its much cheaper than bug branch.

Two caveats, it browsers the repo directly so you will need an internet connection and it doesn't currently support svn+ssh but hosted svn solutions normally use http or https.